# Filters stops after receive thread of input pin sleeps

Tags: c++, directshow

My goal is to make a mux filter that takes three input pins and produces one video that shows images of the sources in fixed interals in seconds.

**Update** 
I changed my synchronisation mechanism, but the problem is still the same: After the first input pin has stopped sending samples and second started, the filter gets stopped

I now use a thread in the filter which sleeps every x seconds and sets a state variable for indicating the current working inputpin:

```
TimeGiver::TimeGiver(int countTimetakers, int millisecondsWait)
{
    running = true;
    this->countTimeTakers = countTimetakers;
    this->waitIntervall = millisecondsWait;
}


TimeGiver::~TimeGiver()
{
}

void TimeGiver::start()
{
    running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->countTimeTakers; i++)
        {
            this->currentOwner = i;

            this->sleep((time_t) this->waitIntervall);

        }

    }
}


bool TimeGiver::isItTimeFor(int id)
{
    return currentOwner == id;
}



void TimeGiver::sleep(time_t delay)
{
    time_t timer0, timer1;
    time(&timer0);
    do
    {
        time(&timer1);
    } while ((timer1 - timer0) < delay);
}

void TimeGiver::stop()
{
    this->running = false;
}
```

the input pins use this as following:

```
HRESULT CMyInputPin::Receive(IMediaSample *pSample)
{

    if (filter->m_pTimeGiver->isItTimeFor(this->m_position))
    {
        std::string strPos = std::to_string(this->m_position);


        std::string message = std::string("In Input receive function (sending data)") + strPos;
        mylogger->LogDebug(message.c_str(), L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
        filter->acceptFilterInput(this->Name(), pSample);
        return S_OK;
    }
    return S_OK;




}
```

So there is no sleeping in the inputpins anymore. But strangely this produces the same result.

Comment: Why do you send the input pins sleeping? Just do nothing with the sample and return immediately.

Comment: but then i don't how many times to return the sample. the goal is that the input pin does not send samples for fixed timeinterval like 5 seconds.

Comment: why don't you just let the filter decide which input-pin accepts samples. And every 5 seconds the filter change a flag on the pins to acceppt input data. If you block the input by sleeping, maybe the camera source filter stops the graph?